# A Question based on non - unit in Local ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

The following question was given as exercise by course instructor in commutative algebra and I was unable to understand one line in it's solution.

So, Posting here.

> Let $P \subseteq A$ be a prime ideal. Let $S= A\setminus P$ . (Then $S$ is multiplicative set) and denote $S^{-1} A$ is denoted by $A_P$. Let $\frac{x}{s} \in A_P $ be a non-unit. Then prove that $x\in P$.

Solution: Let $x$ doesn't belongs to $P$. Let $x\in S$. Then $\frac{s}{x} \in A_p$.

My question is I am not able to understand how $x \in  S$ implies $\frac{s}{x} \in A_P$.

Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is a general element of $S^{-1}A$? It is an equivalence class of the form $\frac{x}{s}$ where $x\in A, s\in S$. If we also have $x\in S$ then $\frac{s}{x}$ is a well defined element in $S^{-1}A$. And indeed:

$\frac{x}{s}\frac{s}{x}=\frac{1}{1}$

So $\frac{s}{x}$ is a multiplicative inverse of $\frac{x}{s}$, which means $\frac{x}{s}$ is a unit.

Comment: Can I ask you another question in comments here!  It doesn't seem so hard so, I think I should not post it as another question. Are you willing to answer it?

Comment: @Avenger Sure, what is the question?

Comment: Thanks you. Let I be an ideal of A. Then I proved that $S^{-1} I= $ {$ x/s: x\in I ,s \in S$} is an ideal of $S^{-1} A$. Then Assume S$\bigcap A  \neq \phi$, How does it implies $S^{-1} I = S^{-1}A$?

Comment: @Avenger I assume you mean $S\cap I\ne\emptyset$, because $S\cap A$ is obviously nonempty. Well, if we have some $s\in S\cap I$ then we have $\frac{1}{1}=\frac{s}{s}\in S^{-1}I$. So the ideal $S^{-1}I$ contains the identity element, which means it must be the whole ring $S^{-1}A$.

Comment: Thank you very much !!